# How To Prevent Rebind For The DetailsView When Hide Or Show Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, detailsview

I have a DetailsView control, in edit mode, I want to hide and show fields based on a DropDownList's value inside it (the DropDownList makes a postback).

The problem is that when a hide and the show operation is maked, the DetailsView control will make a rebind for it and all the filled fields are cleared!

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried if(!Postback) BindTheData();

Comment: I,ve just tried this in the Page_Load but didn't help. if (!IsPostBack) DetailsView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it's the first load or it is a postback, so something like this should help:

```
if (!isPostBack)
{
   // do binding
}
```

Comment: I,ve just tried "if (!IsPostBack) DetailsView1.DataBind();" but didn't help. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You said u r using drop dowlist. I assume ur using SelectedIndexChanged event to perform ur operation. did u set ur dropdown lista auto post back property as true?

if not, try setting

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

that could be a reason.

hope it helps... :)